# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. // Dajaxice, Ajax

Tags: python, django, csrf, django-csrf, dajaxice

I am using Daxice library to create AJAX calls in my Django app.
When I create a `POST` method on a form I get the mentioned error:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

My settings.py have:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.csrf',
)
```

My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from dajaxice.core import dajaxice_autodiscover, dajaxice_config
dajaxice_autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(dajaxice_config.dajaxice_url, include('dajaxice.urls')),
    url(r'^$', 'apps.views.home'),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader, Context

from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def home(request):
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    html = t.render(Context( ))
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

My template index.html:

```
{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}

<html>
  <head>
    <title>My base template</title>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

    {% dajaxice_js_import %}

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function shout(data){
        alert(data.message)

    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
        Page: <input type="text" name="page"><br>
        From: <input type="text" name="from"> (From < To) <br>
        To: <input type="text" name="to"> (returns results before that day)<br>
        <input type="submit" onclick="Dajaxice.apps.hello(shout);" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" onclick="Dajaxice.apps.hello(shout);" value="Get message from server!">

   </body>
</html>
```

And my ajax.py:

```
import simplejson
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
@dajaxice_register(method='POST', name='other_post')
def hello(request):
    return simplejson.dumps({'message':'Hello from Python!'})
```

If I click the button, the message gets alerted. When I submit the form I get this error. How can I fix it?

Finally I believe I have fixed all the possibilities for the CSRF display in the debug page:

```
In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
```

Comment: what version of django do you use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I think I got it. In the line:

```
<form>
...
<input type="submit" onclick="Dajaxice.apps.hello(shout);" value="Submit"></form>
...
</form>
```

If the `type` is `button` it works. It should be something with the `submit` behavior of the server request. I'm not an expert to explain why is this happening, so if somebody can explain I would gladly give the vote.

Comment: if you speak about the button in your second input type, it's normal that's working as it is not in the form .

Comment: I've never been able to track it down, but I've seen the hidden input field generated by the {% csrf_token %} template tag be a little flaky (and use the wrong CSRF token). For debugging purposes, you could add the CSRF token into the <head> of the page as well via: <meta content='{{ csrf_token }}' name='x-csrf-token' />

Then, inspect the source of the page and see if the hidden input matches the csrf token that's present in the head.

Answer (score 1):

According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/) you can send csrf-token on every ajax-post request if you run this script first:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
function sameOrigin(url) {
    // test that a given url is a same-origin URL
    // url could be relative or scheme relative or absolute
    var host = document.location.host; // host + port
    var protocol = document.location.protocol;
    var sr_origin = '//' + host;
    var origin = protocol + sr_origin;
    // Allow absolute or scheme relative URLs to same origin
    return (url == origin || url.slice(0, origin.length + 1) == origin + '/') ||
        (url == sr_origin || url.slice(0, sr_origin.length + 1) == sr_origin + '/') ||
        // or any other URL that isn't scheme relative or absolute i.e relative.
        !(/^(\/\/|http:|https:).*/.test(url));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && sameOrigin(settings.url)) {
            // Send the token to same-origin, relative URLs only.
            // Send the token only if the method warrants CSRF protection
            // Using the CSRFToken value acquired earlier
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

It is written in jquery. If you want vanilla js, visit [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/)

Answer (score 1):

Dajaxice does CSRF handling for you, you don't need any custom jQuery beforeSend code.

But you need to grant Dajaxice access to your CSRF cookie. Therefore:

**Make sure `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` is set to `False` in your settings.py!**